# Spring HandlerInterceptor does not intercept URLs having query parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a HandlerInterceptor which I have defined in spring applicationContext.xml file as below

```
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/**/security/organizations?*" />
        <bean class="com.example.interceptor.PolicyInterceptor"/>
    </mvc:interceptor>
```

Now if I call following URL then the above interceptor is not intercepting the request.

http://localhost:8080/user-management/security/organizations?organizationName=AECS124

any clue?

Comment: And why should it... `*` is single `**` multiple so it will only match if `?` is followed by a single char. Why do you even care about the `?`? Just remove that part leavig `/**/security/organizations`.

Comment: Thanks M. deinum for the quick reply.Actually I have two types of URL patterns.one which does not take any query pareter(like **/security/organizations) and  the other which takes query parameter (like **/security/organizations?orgName=abc).I have a requirement where both the URL patterns would be intercepted by Two different interceptors.Hence I can not directly use **/security/organizations.

Comment: Use a single interceptor, check if there are parameters and dispatch inside that interceptor to do either the check with or without parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Spring uses `org.springframework.util.AntPathMatcher` class to match the path. As per java docs

- ? matches one character
- `*` matches zero or more characters
- `**` matches zero or more directories in a path

It is not recommended to use query parameters in the path matching patterns. It can get complicated.

For your requirement, you can simply use map to

```
<mvc:mapping path="/**/security/organizations" />
```

and code any further logic based on the request parameter, inside your interceptor class.

Comment: Thanks Amit for the quick reply.Actually I have two types of URL patterns.one which does not take any query pareter(like **/security/organizations) and  the other which takes query parameter (like **/security/organizations?orgName=abc).I have a requirement where both the URL patterns would be intercepted by Two different interceptors.Hence I can not directly use **/security/organizations.